# Adding into unordered map containing vector value

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, unordered-map

Let's say I have an unordered map defined as this:

```
unordered_map<string, vector<Obj*>> map // I defined some Obj class
```

If I were to add an element into the map, I would have to do something like:

```
pair<string, vector<Obj*>> newEntry(myString, myVector);
map.insert(newEntry);
```

But I just want to add an element into the vector, what can I do? Do I have to pull out the vector and add to it before inserting it again? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*`std::unordered_map::operator[]`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) as following :

```
map[myString].push_back( new_object ); // new_obj is of type Obj*
```

This will update `myString` key's value, or insert the new key-value if not present.

Also avoid using `map` as variable name, which conflicts with `std::map`

Comment: Is it myVector or myString? I think myVector is valid though.

Comment: @maregor you said you already have a `vector` in a key, where you want to update the vector of existing key, right ? You create a pair of key as `myString` with value `myVector`, so I assume your key is `myString`, as which follows the example